# How do I flatten A Python DataFrame by an index and a list of values?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

Suppose that I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Index': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Values': ['A, B, C, D', 'A, B', 'C', 'D']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Index', 'Values'])

print (df)
```

which creates a DataFrame that looks like this...

```
   Index      Values
0      1  A, B, C, D
1      2        A, B
2      3           C
3      4           D
```

How do I take that Dataframe, and create a new one which looks like this...

```
   Index      Values
0      1           A
1      1           B
2      1           C
3      1           D
4      2           A
5      2           B
6      3           C
7      4           D
```

Comment: `df.assign(Values=df['Values'].str.split(',')).explode('Values')`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.Values = df.Values.str.split(",")
df = df.explode('Values').reset_index(drop=True)


 Index Values
0      1      A
1      1      B
2      1      C
3      1      D
4      2      A
5      2      B
6      3      C
7      4      D
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.